# Animation/s bugging before it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

**Platform:** ASP.Net Web Forms Application

**Tools:** Visual Studio 2013 (Previously 2012)

**Database:** SQL Server 2014 (Local) / SQL Server 2012 (Online)

This is my personal **[website](http://albannurkollari.com)**, which I'm working on. *(Do not hesitate to enter, it's all blank almost and no harm guaranteed as I'm new to web publishing stuff.)*

The scenario I'm trying to achieve is similar to ***MAC OS X Finder*** implementation.
[image]

---

### **Summary of work:**

I've implemented both CSS transitions animations with combos of `addClass()`/`removeClass()`/`toggleClass()` via jQuery methods aswell as implemented `.animate()` for a certain part of the project. The first ones are used to animate the interactions of books, e.g. selecting one distinguishes it from the rest of the books by transitioning several properties of the elements (border, color, opacity, etc.) even so applied on pseudo-classes like :hover. The latter (.animate) is tied on the idea to make a smooth horizontally scroll-able content. In practice, when selecting another book from the current one, it moves the whole container of the books left/right. I've added arrow keys functionality (<kbd>**←**</kbd> and <kbd>**→**</kbd>) to navigate between books.

---

### **PROBLEM:**

Everything is fine *(*not bragging!*)* written until the point of bugging(spamming inputs) to the site. If you were to navigate fast between books for which I've assigned the keys mentioned above, it will bug the animate left/right of the book container aswell as glitching few books from changing their respectful classes.

P.s.: I haven't done any fiddle nor code snippet in here due to the fact that everything is visible from the web-page to the client-side via Inspect Element of your browser. In case one requests to provide the code I won't hesitate to Edit my question.

Comment: Please add code or a fiddle. If we suggest fixes to your site, the link wont help anyone else with the same issues (as the link will be fixed). I fyou add code here then it will help others

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/70m64tz2/3/

Answer (score 0):

How about this implementation.

**replace**

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            var prevBook = $(".bookMain").prev()[0];
            selectBook(prevBook);
            break;

        case 39: // right
            var nextBook = $(".bookMain").next()[0];
            selectBook(nextBook);
            break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

**with**

```
var animation = false;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            if(!animation){
                animation = true;
                var prevBook = $(".bookMain").prev()[0];
                if(typeof prevBook == "undefined")
                    animation = false;
                else
                    selectBook(prevBook);
                setTimeout(function(){animation = false;},500);
            }
            break;

        case 39: // right
            if(!animation){
                animation = true;
                var nextBook = $(".bookMain").next()[0];
                if(typeof nextBook == "undefined")
                    animation = false;
                else
                    selectBook(nextBook);
                setTimeout(function(){animation = false;},500);
            }
            break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

**UPDATE**

Added an if condition to solve a console error which was coming when ever the right is pressed in the last slide and left is pressed from first slide

Comment: Your approach is the answer. But one thing I noticed is that it doesn't give the flow of fast navigating through elements. Is there any possibility like to disable animation/s when either of the keys is long-pressed(hold)?

Comment: Any keyword so that I define my search in a better scope would be useful for me if you happen to know and willing to share with me. Thanks in advance anyway.